# How to convert sql inner join query into linq to sql query and convert into list

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, linq, join

I have below class:

```
public class customRequest
{
    public string REQ_STATUS { get; set; }
    public DateTime REQ_RVE_DATnTIM { get; set; }
    public string EMP_FNAME { get; set; }
    public string EVE_CAT_NAME { get; set; }
    public string EVE_NAME { get; set; }
}
```

and below SQL Inner Join Query which works perfect in SQL:

```
SELECT req.REQ_STATUS,req.REQ_RVE_DATnTIM, emp.EMP_FNAME, cat.EVE_CAT_NAME,eve.EVE_NAME from REQUESTS req inner join Employees emp on req.REQ_EMP_ID = emp.ID inner join EVENTCATEGORIES cat on req.REQ_EVE_CAT_ID = cat.ID inner join EVENTS eve on req.REQ_EVE_NAM_ID = eve.ID order by req.REQ_STATUS
```

What I want is to convert it into my linq to sql query. Below is my Linq to Sql query which I tried:

```
slist = from req in db.REQUESTS
                    join emp in db.Employees on req.REQ_EMP_ID equals emp.ID
                    join cat in db.EVENTCATEGORIES on req.REQ_EVE_CAT_ID equals cat.ID
                    join eve in db.EVENTS on req.REQ_EVE_NAM_ID equals eve.ID
                    select new { req.REQ_STATUS, req.REQ_RVE_DATnTIM, emp.EMP_FNAME, cat.EVE_CAT_NAME, eve.EVE_NAME };
        return slist.ToList();
```

But it shows me an error on last join:

> Error 1   Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Linq.IQueryable' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'. An explicit conversion exists (are you missing a cast?)    H:\64bit\Project Finalizing\Blue_Pumpkin\Blue_Pumpkin\Admin\Requests.aspx.cs    32  25  Blue_Pumpkin

Comment: Try returning `slist.ToList()`.

Comment: Yes I tried but same error is shown at last join.

Comment: Can you post the whole function?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm assuming you wish to return a `customRequest` class from your query. You need to explicitly cast your select statement as `customRequest`..

```
slist = (from req in db.REQUESTS
                    join emp in db.Employees on req.REQ_EMP_ID equals emp.ID
                    join cat in db.EVENTCATEGORIES on req.REQ_EVE_CAT_ID equals cat.ID
                    join eve in db.EVENTS on req.REQ_EVE_NAM_ID equals eve.ID
                    select new customRequest {
                       REQ_STATUS = req.REQ_STATUS, req.REQ_RVE_DATnTIM, 
                       EMP_FNAME = emp.EMP_FNAME, 
                       EVE_CAT_NAME = cat.EVE_CAT_NAME, 
                       EVE_NAME = eve.EVE_NAME }).ToList();
            return slist;
```

If it so happens that you do need to return a list.. You need to declare your return type as a list variable and use `ToList()` from there, if you are to return a single row result set then you can use `First()` or `FirstOrDefault()`

Comment: Appreciate your effort @matchesMalone. I just do small changes in your code and got it what I want. Below is my edited code

Comment: `select new customRequest
                     {
                         REQ_STATUS = req.REQ_STATUS,
                         REQ_RVE_DATnTIM =      (DateTime)req.REQ_RVE_DATnTIM,
                         EMP_FNAME = emp.EMP_FNAME,
                         EVE_CAT_NAME = cat.EVE_CAT_NAME,
                         EVE_NAME = eve.EVE_NAME
                     }).ToList();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use ToList() along with your linq query :

```
var slist = (from req in db.REQUESTS
                join emp in db.Employees on req.REQ_EMP_ID equals emp.ID
                join cat in db.EVENTCATEGORIES on req.REQ_EVE_CAT_ID equals cat.ID
                join eve in db.EVENTS on req.REQ_EVE_NAM_ID equals eve.ID
                select new select new customRequest {
                   REQ_STATUS = req.REQ_STATUS,
                   REQ_RVE_DATnTIM= req.REQ_RVE_DATnTIM, 
                   EMP_FNAME = emp.EMP_FNAME, 
                   EVE_CAT_NAME = cat.EVE_CAT_NAME, 
                   EVE_NAME = eve.EVE_NAME }){
                   REQ_STATUS = req.REQ_STATUS, req.REQ_RVE_DATnTIM, 
                   EMP_FNAME = emp.EMP_FNAME, 
                   EVE_CAT_NAME = cat.EVE_CAT_NAME, 
                   EVE_NAME = eve.EVE_NAME }).ToList();
```

Comment: It showing me an error `Error 1 Cannot initialize type 'Error 1 Cannot initialize type 'Blue_Pumpkin.Admin.customRequest' with a collection initializer because it does not implement 'System.Collections.IEnumerable' F:\64bit\Project Finalizing\Blue_Pumpkin\Blue_Pumpkin\Admin\Requests.aspx.cs 33 50 Blue_Pumpkin`

Comment: How did you delcared 'slist' variable, is it an object of you class .?

Comment: Its in my method `var slist = new List<customRequest >();`

Comment: see my answer @AhmerAliAhsan

Comment: Thanks for your effort @Sahi but I got my solution in MatchesMalone post.